# C# WPF изменение размера кнопок при изменение размера окна

Tags: c#, wpf

Подскажите как сделать чтобы при изменение окна, менялся размер кнопок

```
<Grid>
    <Grid ShowGridLines="True">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <DockPanel Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Width="Auto" Height="40" >
            <TextBlock Text="Example" FontSize="30" Margin="5,0,0,0"></TextBlock>
        </DockPanel>
        <DockPanel Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Grid.ColumnSpan="1" Width="Auto" >
            <Button Style="{DynamicResource BtnStyle}" Foreground="White" x:Name="BtnStatistic" Content="Статистика" Margin="-355,5,0,0" Width="112"></Button>
            <Button Style="{DynamicResource BtnStyle}" Foreground="White" x:Name="BtnSetting" Grid.ColumnSpan="1" Content="Настройки" Margin="-122,5,0,0" Width="112"></Button>
        </DockPanel>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Comment: [Адаптивный интерфейс](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1295679/220553), [Создание элемента с масштабируемостью](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1204654/220553)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно разбить Grid на 3 колонки с равной шириной и сделать кнопки четко привязанными к одной из 3-х колонок Grid'a.
Обратите внимание на Grid.Column у кнопок, у TextBlock'a свойство можно не указывать, т.к. по дефолту там будет Grid.Column="0" (первая колонка).

```
<Grid ShowGridLines="True">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <TextBlock Text="Example" 
               FontSize="30" 
               Margin="5,0,0,0"/>

    <Button Style="{DynamicResource BtnStyle}" 
            Foreground="White" 
            x:Name="BtnStatistic" 
            Content="Статистика"
            Grid.Column="1"/>

    <Button Style="{DynamicResource BtnStyle}" 
            Foreground="White"
            x:Name="BtnSetting" 
            Grid.Column="2"
            Content="Настройки"/>
</Grid>
```

Comment: хитро, удобный способ и не требует хранения элементов в контейнерах отдельных
Подправил тут чтобы пропорционально растягивалось
<Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="0.2*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="0.2*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

И через margin сделал отступы
<Button Style="{DynamicResource BtnStyle}" 
            Foreground="White" 
            x:Name="BtnStatistic" 
            Content="Статистика"
            Margin="5,5,0,0"
            Grid.Column="1"/>

Comment: Если хотите, чтобы кнопки, например, занимали меньше места, то да, ширину можно указать как 0.2*

Comment: а подскажите как можно ограничить растягивание кнопки по высоте, в ширину растягивается как надо, а по высоте слишком много.

Comment: 2 варианта - 1) ограничить высоту строки грида; 2) MaxHeight

Comment: спасибо еще раз) Со вторым вариантом растягивается как надо) А с первым не нашел пример в гугл или инфу.

Comment: Строка грида задается как <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>, ничто не мешает вам в Height вставить что угодно (число, 0.2*, *, 2*, etc...)

Comment: <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition MaxHeight="50"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
Работает для всех элементов)

Comment: Верно, поэтому если вы хотите, например, чтобы изменялась высота только у TextBlock'a, но не у кнопок - 2 варианта: Вариант №1 - разбить строку (gridRow) на строки (Grid внутри Grid'a, у которого будет установлено свойство Grid.Row="1" (например)) и в нем сделать несколько строк (например 3), где 3 из них будет занимать TextBlock (Grid.RowSpan="3"), а кнопки по 1 (Grid.Row="1"); Вариант №2 - сделать всё тоже самое, что в варианте №1, но не делать грид в гриде, а в главном гриде добавить строки :)