# Сохранить пропорции интерфейса при изменении размера окна

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

я пытался сохранить пропорции элементов (Border) при помощи матана, но это не увенчалось успехом, так что хотелось узнать, как лучше и грамотнее реализовать подгон интерфейса [image: как должно выглядеть при любом размере окна] [image: как получается]

Comment: Опишите задачу подробнее, какую именно пропорцию вы хотите сохранить?

Comment: я бы хотел сохранить относительный размер фрагментов, те, чтобы при изменении размера окна общий вид сохранялся (при уменьшении окна уменьшались и элементы а при увеличении увеличивались)

Comment: То, что у вас сверху все сплющилось означает то, что вы не так разместили элементы, не так настроили сетку. Если вам надо, чтобы у элементов менялся размер, то используйте [ViewBox](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1204654/220553).

Answer (score 0):

решение в лоб - стандартными средствами:

```
<Grid Name="grdBody">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="5*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="5*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Border Name="brd1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="6" Grid.RowSpan="1" Background="RosyBrown" SizeChanged="brd1_SizeChanged">
        <Label Name="lbl1" Margin="0,2,0,2" Padding="4" Background="Brown" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Content="Time and Day" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
    </Border>

    <Border Name="brd2" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.RowSpan="1" Background="Wheat">
        <Label Name="lbl2" Margin="0,2,0,2" Padding="4" Background="Brown" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Content="weather day" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
    </Border>
    <Border Name="brd3" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="4" Grid.RowSpan="1" Background="LightBlue">
        <Label Name="lbl3" Margin="0,2,0,2" Padding="4" Background="Brown" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Content="weather weak" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
    </Border>

    <Border Name="brd4" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Grid.RowSpan="1" Background="Silver">
        <Label Name="lbl4" Margin="0,2,0,2" Padding="4" Background="Brown" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Content="NET чотатам" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
    </Border>
    <Border Name="brd5" Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Grid.RowSpan="1" Background="DarkBlue">
        <Label Name="lbl5" Margin="0,2,0,2" Padding="4" Background="Brown" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Content="app status" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
    </Border>
</Grid>
```

и

```
    private void brd1_SizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        double h1 = brd1.ActualHeight;
        if (h1 < 18 || double.IsNaN(h1) || double.IsInfinity(h1))
            return;

        double h2 = h1 - 18;
        lbl1.FontSize = h2;
        lbl2.FontSize = h2;
        lbl3.FontSize = h2;
        lbl4.FontSize = h2;
        lbl5.FontSize = h2; 
    }
```

масштабирование текста исключительно от высоты 1й строки, а её высота - от высоты всего окна... но общий смысл, я думаю, понятен)

Comment: Тут кстати вы тоже пошли в такие дебри, когда можно было просто обернуть весь (или только нужные элементы) в **стандартный** `ViewBox`, задачка решается чисто XAML разметкой, а вы тут свои костыли пишете... Не, решение мб и уместно, но не представляю кто будет подобное писать)