# Как реализовать у элемента соотношение сторон 1х1?

Tags: wpf, xaml

Допустим у меня есть какой-то график LiveCharts. Мне необходимо, чтобы при изменении размера окна его длина и ширина были в соотношении 1x1.

Код XAML:

```
 <Grid Background="#f5f5f5">
     <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
         <ColumnDefinition Width="5" />
         <ColumnDefinition />
         <ColumnDefinition Width="5" />
     </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
     <Grid.RowDefinitions>
         <RowDefinition Height="5" />
         <RowDefinition />
         <RowDefinition Height="5" />
         <RowDefinition Height="40"/>
         <RowDefinition Height="5" />
     </Grid.RowDefinitions>

     <DockPanel Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Margin="5" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
         <StackPanel DockPanel.Dock="Top" Orientation="Horizontal">
             <Label Content="Номер сечения:"        Width="120" />
             <Label Content="{Binding SliderValue}" Width="100" />
         </StackPanel>

         <lvc:CartesianChart DockPanel.Dock="Top" DisableAnimations="True" LegendLocation="Top">
              <!-- Здесь какой-то график -->
         </lvc:CartesianChart>

     </DockPanel>

     <DockPanel Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
         <StackPanel DockPanel.Dock="Left">
             <Slider Value="{Binding SliderValue, Mode=TwoWay}" Margin="5" SelectionStart="0" Minimum="0" Maximum="299" TickPlacement="BottomRight" TickFrequency="1" IsSnapToTickEnabled="True" IsSelectionRangeEnabled="True" />
         </StackPanel>
     </DockPanel>
 </Grid>
```

Comment: `ViewBox` с его свойством `Stretch` вам помогут ([пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1204654/220553))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Получилось с помощью [комментария](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1555226/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%83-%d1%8d%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b0-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%be%d1%82%d0%bd%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%81%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d0%be%d0%bd-1%d1%851#comment2801099_1555226):

```
<Viewbox Stretch="Uniform">
     <lvc:CartesianChart Width="500" Height="500" DisableAnimations="True" LegendLocation="Top">
     <!-- Здесь какой-то график -->
     </lvc:CartesianChart>
</Viewbox>
```